# How to get current outcome in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I would like to get outcome value from navigation rules into a request scoped JSF 2 bean. How can I do that?

For example, when I press on a `<h:link outcome="contacts">` and end up in the contacts page, then I would like to get the outcome `"contacts"` in the backing bean associated with the navigation menu.

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    ...
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>contacts</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/contacts.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    ...
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: You have a lot of outcome variables ?

Comment: Not so. I just wanna get outcome for disable h:link into menu

Comment: You need to hard-code in backing bean.

Comment: I'll do it only as temporary solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can get current url, and then compare to faces-config's content !

Comment: I thought about that. I think it's bad idea, because of url can have more than one outcome. It depends on conditions.

Comment: You would just like to disable h:link when it was clicked ?

Comment: I wanna disable link from menu if current page is loaded

Comment: `url can have more than one outcome`: why you want to do that ?

Comment: I don't need to-view-id value. I just wanna get from-outcome value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JSF, AFAIK, only the `ConfigurableNavigationHandler` will have that information. So create a custom `ConfigurableNavigationHandler` that will stash the outcome in a request parameter for your consumption in the destination page.

1. Your custom navigation handler

   ```
   public class NavigationHandlerTest extends ConfigurableNavigationHandler {

   private NavigationHandlerTest concreteHandler;

      public NavigationHandlerTest(NavigationHandler concreteHandler) {
       this.concreteHandler = concreteHandler;
      }


   @Override
      public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String fromAction, String    outcome){
       //Grab a hold of the request parameter part and save the outcome in it for
       //later retrieval
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ctx = context.getExternalContext();
        ctx.getRequestMap().put("currentOutcome", outcome);

       //resume normal navigation
        concreteHandler.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, outcome);   
       }   
     }
   ```
2. Configure your handler in *faces-config.xml*

   ```
     <application>
        <navigation-handler>com.foo.bar.NavigationHandlerTest</navigation-handler>
     </application>
   ```
3. Retrieve in your destination bean

   ```
     @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.currentOutcome}")
     String outcome;
     //getter and setter
   ```